# the dns server ping use is different from the dns server nslookup use

Tags: windows, dns, ping, nslookup

on my computer(windows 10), the dns server that ping.exe use is different from the dns server nslookup use. i set 192.168.123.1 to be my computer's dns server, which is my router. so nslookup uses it as the dns server:

```
PS C:\Users\peter> nslookup.exe fm.zju.edu.cn
server:  RT-N14U.lan
Address:  192.168.123.1

name:    fm.zju.edu.cn
Address:  10.214.0.99
```

this ip address ic correct, which is school-internal ip.
but the ping result is different:

```
PS C:\Users\peter> ipconfig.exe /flushdns

Windows IP Configuration

Successfully flushed the DNS Resolver Cache.
PS C:\Users\peter> ping fm.zju.edu.cn

Pinging fm.zju.edu.cn [210.32.157.99] with 32 bytes of data:
```

then i use wireshark to find out that ping.exe send dns request to another dns server 114.114.114.114. i used to use this dns server, but i doesn't use it for about a month.
i reset the network settings, but the ping.exe still use 114.114.114.114 as its dns server.
i don't know how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know why this problem disappear today, what i did yesterday was:
change the mtu value of network card from 1500 to 1280 and many other things.
if this problem never appears again, just let it pass.